# TWRequest Caching

Tags: ios5, twitter, twrequest

I use TWRequest in ios5 to fetch avatars for user accounts.

The returned image data doesn't seem to be cached. If I check the Cache.db sqlite database, there are records for all images, however, they contain no data.

Is there any easy way to enable caching of avatars (images) with TWRequest?